# Graphite null value response

Tags: grafana

I faced with a problem on grafana dashboard accordance to metric request to graphite.

I have the similar request:
`summarize(awsMetricName.Sum, '1h', avg, true)`

I set from-to range in 3 hours and try to send request, I got the result with timestamp point, but values were null in them.

But having made some same requests  the data could be returned

Also when I decrease from-to range to 30inutes, this request worked properly.

May be someone faced with the same problem?

Updated: I wanna determine the reason, why graphite sometimes returns data normally and sometimes null.

Updated: Отправляю реквест на графит (описан выше), иногда возвращаются налы иногда нормальные данные. Данных на графите много, полагаю, что не всегда успевает обработать запрос, хотелось бы узнать, может кто сталкивался, с чем может быть связана эта проблема.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.